# Stop breadcrumb function retrieving custom post type template name

Tags: php, functions, breadcrumb

I have created a function that pulls in the breadcrumb of a page/post. However, I am having a problem where it appears to pull in the custom post-type template name rather than the actual name of the post.

```
    function get_breadcrumb() {

    global $post;

    $trail = '';
    $page_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
    $url = $protocol;

    if($post->post_parent) {
        $parent_id = $post->post_parent;

        while ($parent_id) {
            $page = get_page($parent_id);
            $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="#">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a> » ';
            $parent_id = $page->post_parent;
        }

        $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
        foreach($breadcrumbs as $crumb) $trail .= $crumb;
    }

    $trail .= '<a href="#">' . 'Home' . '</a> ' . '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $page_title . '</a>';     
    $trail .= '';

    return $trail;  
    
add_shortcode('breadcrumbs', 'get_breadcrumb');
```

In the custom post-type template file, I have pulled in a page template using a shortcode to the plug-in extension Templatera. This plug-in allowed me to create the page template with the wpbakery builder and then link it to the custom post-type template file.

Below is the shortcode which pulls in the template in the custom post-type template file.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[templatera id="254"]'); ?>
```

Here is a link to one of the posts so that you are able to see it is displaying the shortcode template name rather than the actual post name:

https://snapstaging.co.uk/coolkitnew/vans/citroen-relay-x-l2-h2-mwb/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try replacing ` $page_title = get_the_title($post->ID);` with just ` $page_title = get_the_title();`.  I'm not sure but it looks like this is being called within the loop

Comment: I have tried changing the code to the above. Unfortunately, nothing appeared to change. @rudtek